# PHP replace BBcode tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm working on creating a bulletin board converter. I need PHP to replace/restructure the following from:

```
[img alt="" src="IMAGE LINK, NOT ENDING IN AN IMAGE FORMAT EXTENSION" style="max-width:100%;"]
```

To:

```
[img]IMAGE LINK[/img]
```

Where everything else such as the alt tags can be deleted.

At the moment I have PHP use `preg_replace` (in an array) and I am using regex to try and obtain the link. However I'm struggling on finding a way to convert it over, as I've not used regex before.

Apologies for the hassle, and thank you very much! :)

Comment: What do you mean with: `NOT ENDING IN AN IMAGE FORMAT EXTENSION`? Couldd you give some examples and expected result for all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you will need something like this

```
<?php
$string = '[img alt="" src="IMAGE LINK, NOT ENDING IN AN IMAGE FORMAT EXTENSION" style="max-width:100%;"]';

$matches = array();
print preg_replace('|\[img.*src="(.*)" style.*]|', '[img]$1[/img]', $string);
```

prints

> [img]IMAGE LINK, NOT ENDING IN AN IMAGE FORMAT EXTENSION[/img]

Answer (score 1):

For your regex this is cleaner

```
\[img[^\]]+?src="([^"]*)"[^\]]*\]
```

Replacement is the same you had.

You need the `?` for laziness otherwise you will have unexpected matches
For instance the first answer regex matches `[img src="img1" style] [img 2] [img 3]` not what you want